# Ethernet: two input signals to one pc

Tags: routing, ethernet

In the particular setting that I have, a regular pc needs to be connected with an extrernal lab device via ethernet to establish communication between the two.

On the other hand, the same pc is required to be connected to the local network by ethernet as well, of course.

One port available, two inputs.

What's the workaround here?

Do I need to go for a switch, a splitter, a hub or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the two connections should remain separate from each other, as the lab device might require different IP configuration than your local network does (and probably is not supposed to interact with the local network for security).

In this case, none of the above. You want to get a second completely separate Ethernet interface instead. (There are PCI and PCI-E cards for desktops, as well as USB Ethernet adapters for laptops.)

On the other hand, if the lab device *is* supposed to be part of your LAN network, you would want an Ethernet switch. (Note that most devices nowadays sold as "hubs" are switches, not actual hubs.)

Passive Ethernet splitters aren't suitable for either task. They don't "merge" the signals, only carry two separate signals over one cable that needs to be split back into two ports again.

Comment: You hit the spot right there: 

"the lab device might require different IP configuration than your local network does "

It is exactly that the case. 

So, a second network adapter is required. 
Many thanks!